# Golang - Gracefully stop ReadFromUDP when UDP connection closes

Tags: go, udp

So, we have a full-duplex system setup that utilizes channels and different goroutines for UDP packet processing (reading, writing, handling). Thus, we block at `ReadFromUDP` while waiting for incoming packets in a goroutine.

We have this peculiar problem with `ReadFromUDP` throwing an error (obviously) while waiting for a packet to arrive and the connection is being closed elsewhere.

The error that is printed is the following:

> read udp 127.0.0.1:8091: use of closed network connection

This is quite reasonable since we actually close the connection in another goroutine via channels.

Is there anyone who knows if there exists a way of not getting that error (other than catching it) when this occurs or if there exists another way to signal `ReadFromUDP` to stop reading, without using timeouts?

Comment: Eh, hacky, but you could do a check on that string and have a function that returns a custom error if you find "use of closed network connection", or the original err if the string doesn't match. Then you could check if err != CustomErr {}.

Comment: Yeah, we had thought of something similar, but as you said, that is a bit hacky ;)

Comment: You can't get aroung the error. You closed connection while read operation is in progress. To determine if that error is ok you need some kind of a flag that tells your code that connection was closed normally and errors in read operations should be ignored. Don't use timeout in this case. Use the error. Remember, errors are values and should be used that way i.e. should be used in actual program logic.

Comment: Right now we actually use the error plus a signaling channel (as you wrote) to determine if it is ok to close or if we should continue. But was looking for an alternative, more "robust" way of doing it other than comparing error strings.

Comment: Why do you need to compare strings? First, network error contains the reason why it happened. Second, your code knows that you closed connection and it means any error from read operation should be ignored. You don't need error string in either case.

Comment: @creker we shouldn't assume that any error handed back from his call is due to a closed UDP connection.

Comment: @william.taylor.09, that's why you have the flag. If it's set you don't care about errors. If it isn't then you can check the error and act accordingly. If you still want to check the error there is `net.errClosing` package variable. No string comparisons needed